# All Inertia requests must receive a valid Inertia response, however a plain JSON response was received

Tags: svelte, inertiajs, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

I have a problem using routes with inertia, I'm using AdonisJS + Inertia + Svelte

Everything running perfectly, but when clicking on links of routes it only returns me this problem

**My Home.svelte:**

[image]

**My router:**

```
Route.get('/second', 'SecondsController.index')
```

**Controller:**

```
import { HttpContextContract } from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext'

export default class PostsController {
  public async index({ inertia }: HttpContextContract) {
    const mydata = {
        title: "Second Page",
        content: "Some content here.",
      };

    return inertia.render('Second', { mydata })
  }
}
```

Message I receive when clicking on the link:
[image]

This message simply appears and does not go to the other page

Comment: what are you returning inside the `SecondsController.index`?

Comment: <script>
  import { inertia, Link } from "@inertiajs/inertia-svelte";
  export let data;
</script>

<h1>Title: {data.title}</h1>
<p>{data.content}</p>
<Link href="/">Home</Link>

Comment: okay, didn't mean this. well, can u share the `SecondsController.index` method?